# Modal with JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a problem with creating modal with calling a JSON file. My 'click' events do not work with the authoring system, whereas if I code the link and the modal in my HTML file it works.

```
projectUi(items){
    let result = ' ';
    items.map(item=>{
        result +=`
            <div class="details-project">
               <a class="js-modal" href="#${item.modal}"></a>
            </div>


        <aside style="display: none;" id="${item.modal}" class="modal" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="titleModal">
            <div class="modal-wrapper js-modal-stop">
                <button class="js-modal-close">Fermer</button>
                <h1 id="titleModal">Titre ${item.modal}</h2>
            </div>
        </aside>
        `
    });
    const allPortfolio = document.querySelector('.all-portfolio');
    allPortfolio.innerHTML = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your webpage in browser then Press F12 then navigate to console tab. There you can see all the errors occuring in your webpage. Hope you solve that error :) .
**Make sure to override display:none property.**
If you don't succeed to solve it then please show us the error message.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I have no error in the console ^^